# How to configure Nginx behind a corporate proxy

Tags: nginx

Is there an equivalent of Apache's `ProxyRemote` directive for NginX?

So the scenario is I am behind a corporate proxy and I want to do proxy passes for various services with NginX. I would do it in Apache with the following:

```
ProxyPass        /localStackOverflow/ https://stackoverflow.com/
ProxyPassReverse /localStackOverflow/ https://stackoverflow.com/
ProxyRemote https://stackoverflow.com/ http://(my corporate proxy IP)
```

I know I need the `proxy_pass` directive in Nginx but can't find what I would use for the `ProxyRemote`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The servers you proxy behind an Nginx front-end web server are referred to as upstream servers. You will want to refer to the documentation for the [HttpUpstreamModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule). It's very similair to what you are familiar with. If you don't need load-balancing, you just setup the one upstream server in the configuration and it will serve your purpose.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question, perhaps I'm missing something?  ProxyPass can take upstream servers as a param which is handy for load balancing, but how to ensure those requests are through something like http_proxy env var - e.g. for the corporate firewall use case he mentioned?  Asking as I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII it works for me. Maybe they fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how @tacos response can work - possibly something I'm missing but the only way I could sort of get this to work was by rewriting the url and passing on to the corporate proxy.  This is shown below:

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
          rewrite ^(.*)$ "http://www.externalsite.com$1" break;
          proxy_pass http://corporate-proxy.mycorp.com:8080;
    }
  }
}
```

This works, but does rewrite the url, not sure if this is important to the original use-case..

Comment: This just sends a redirect (302) to the client. The proxy_pass line is not involved.